# Diagramming Software

Tags: data-visualization, diagram

I do a lot of diagramming showing how data flows throughout an organization to non-IT people. Currently using Visio, but spend way too much time rearranging icons and arrows. Would love software that allows me to define the properties and relationships between objects, then have the software automatically arrange the objects with all the appropriate lines.

Liked GraphViz, but not WYSIWYG or user friendly enough for other team members I work with.

Would Like To Haves: (1) Windows based, (2) Assign properties and relationships to objects, (3) Automatically arrange icons, arrows, and labels, etc., (4) Custom Icons, (5) Custom Labels, and (6) Template Icon/Labels.

What I'm NOT looking for: (1) Basic flowchart software, (2) UML diagram software, and (3) Software that requires manual rearrangement of objects and lines.

Comment: Welcome.  Are you looking for recommendations for gratis software or commercial software?

Comment: https://opensource.com/life/14/6/tools-diagramming-fedora   Maybe dia, its is free.

Comment: Commercial or freeware, both are fine. Tried Dia a while back, does it now have auto-align type feature? Is the assigning done via object properties or by clicking and dragging the icons?

Answer (score 2):

You can use OrgChart JS provided by [BALKANGraph](https://balkangraph.com/), it support all features from your requirement

OrgChart JS lets developers to create simple, flexible and highly customizable organization chart for presenting structural data in an elegant way

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Syncfusion Diagram have support to create and arrange data in the Organizational Chart structure. Please find the sample and screenshot as below.

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/5myckm-a1tfk2?file=index.js

Please find the documentation for how to create node and how to add image to node as below.

Link (how to create node):https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/diagram/nodes/

Link (how to add image to node) : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/diagram/shapes/#image

Answer (score 1):

This is a belated response, perhaps can be useful to some. There is one diagramming software [MyDraw](https://www.mydraw.com/) which I have also started using not a long time back.

I think this could meet some of your requirements. In addition the learning curve is not complicated. A bonus is that it is compatible with Visio hence you can still import and edit diagrams that were started with Visio.

Some of its features are outlined:

- Many MyDraw shapes have control points, which allow you to visually
  modify specific aspects of their geometry. The technology behind this
  is similar to the Microsoft Visio® “smart-shapes” technology.
- MyDraw shapes can contain raster images (.BMP, .PNG, .JPG etc.) and
  also vector images in .WMF and .EMF format.
- **MyDraw features routable connectors that automatically reroute when
  you mode their end-points. This allows you to create perfectly
  connected diagrams.**
- MyDraw also features strong support for shapes library management,
  which allows you to create your libraries.

You can read more here: https://www.mydraw.com/features-features

Screenshot

[image]